# Porque no me cargan los lineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(!index.isValid()){
        return;
    }

    QString id=mModel->data(mModel->index(index.row(),0)).toString();

    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec(QString("SELECT id_elemento,id_grupo,id_tipo,nombre,descripcion,icono FROM elemento WHERE id_elemento= " + id +";"));
    qDebug()<<id;
    q.first();
    QPixmap pixmap;
    if(!pixmap.loadFromData(q.value(5).toByteArray())){
        labelImg->setText("<b>Error de Imagen</b>");

    }

    lineCod->setText(q.value(0).toString());
    lineGroup->setText(q.value(1).toString());
    lineType->setText(q.value(2).toString());
    lineName->setText(q.value(3).toString());
    textDescription->setPlainText(q.value(4).toString());
    lineImg->setText(q.value(5).toString());
    labelImg->setPixmap(pixmap);

}

/*resultado
"R-1 " el id es el correcto
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

 */
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no los carga? ¿Has verificado que la consulta se ejecuta correctamente?

Comment: La consulta funciona bien y esta testada desde PostgresSql,

Comment: No me rellena los lineEdit con los datos de la consulta

Comment: Ya lo arregle tuve que añadir comillas simples antes del QString id